# Error in Geomesa shapefile ingest

Tags: shapefile, geomesa

I am trying to ingest a point shapefile to geomesa, I have added the schema and convertor part to conf file but when i am giving the ingest command usinf geomesa-fs it is giving me the below error.

**

> ERROR Warning: Missing dependency for command execution: Could not
>   initialize class
>   org.locationtech.geomesa.fs.FileSystemDataStoreFactory$

**

Anyone got any idea how it can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates that your classpath is not complete. Did you follow the installation instructions [here](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/filesystem/install.html#setting-up-the-filesystem-command-line-tools)?

Comment: Actually, it was the error of hadoop installation, It was not installed correctly. I have another question, When I am trying to ingest shapefile using schema and converter both, it's failing and I am not able to figure out the error. I am getting this error **Ingested 0 features and failed to ingest 52 features for file: /home/ec2-user/geomesa-data/cb_2017_us_state_20m.shp** I am using the same file as given in the shapefile convertor example

Comment: @RohitSingh Please open a new thread for new questions.